# React Drawer State Management

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, drawer

I put together a page with Sidebar on left, Appbar at top and content area. It was all working properly as one single Gigantic component. The idea and flexibility, I assume, we all love with React is making various elements on the page different components. Therefore, I went ahead and made the Sidebar, Appbar, Content area their own components. Obviously, there's a state problem now, because I can't think of a way to change the State of the Sidebar from hidden to shown so appropriate changes take place on the page.

Now bringing in the question, how is State management with React still seem optional and many recommend for only large projects? I couldn't do a simple project with Sidebar in it without State management? There might be ways to address this particular issue like getting clicks onto the main component like App.js and sending that to each and every single component every time user clicks the button. I mean, impossible is nothing but, it's not really a good solution.

Lastly, for strict coders out there that wants to see a code, I used Material UI, Persistent Drawer here: https://material-ui.com/demos/drawers/

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  appBarShift: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  hide: {
    display: 'none',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: '0 8px',
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: -drawerWidth,
  },
  contentShift: {
    transition: theme.transitions.create('margin', {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
});

class PersistentDrawerLeft extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={classNames(classes.appBar, {
            [classes.appBarShift]: open,
          })}
        >
          <Toolbar disableGutters={!open}>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="Open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerOpen}
              className={classNames(classes.menuButton, open && classes.hide)}
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
              Persistent drawer
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Drawer
          className={classes.drawer}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={open}
          classes={{
            paper: classes.drawerPaper,
          }}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
            <IconButton onClick={this.handleDrawerClose}>
              {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : <ChevronRightIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </div>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
          <Divider />
          <List>
            {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
              <ListItem button key={text}>
                <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <main
          className={classNames(classes.content, {
            [classes.contentShift]: open,
          })}
        >
          <div className={classes.drawerHeader} />
          <Typography paragraph>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent
            elementum facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in
            hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum
            velit laoreet id donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing.
            Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis
            viverra nibh cras. Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo.
            Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus
            at augue. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed
            ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
          </Typography>
          <Typography paragraph>
            Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
            facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
            tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
            consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus
            sed vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in.
            In hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem
            et tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique
            sollicitudin nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo
            viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam
            ultrices sagittis orci a.
          </Typography>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PersistentDrawerLeft.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(PersistentDrawerLeft);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state will continue to be managed as it was before splitting the components -- at the highest level that is in common for all the descendant components that need it. That state as well as any callbacks that manage the state will be passed as props to the child components that need it.

Here's what the top-level component would look like:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import MyAppBar from "./MyAppBar";
import MyContent from "./MyContent";
import MyDrawer from "./MyDrawer";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: "0 8px",
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
});

class PersistentDrawerLeft extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleDrawerClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { open } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <MyAppBar handleDrawerOpen={this.handleDrawerOpen} open={open} />
        <MyDrawer
          handleDrawerClose={this.handleDrawerClose}
          drawerHeaderClass={classes.drawerHeader}
          open={open}
        />
        <MyContent drawerHeaderClass={classes.drawerHeader} open={open} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PersistentDrawerLeft.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(PersistentDrawerLeft);
```

The other components are then fairly straightforward. You can see all the pieces in the sandbox.

[image: Edit Drawer split into components]

Comment: what if Slider is inside AppBar and AppBar is inside App.js. The IconButton is mentioned inside AppBar. So user would click on IconButton in AppBar which needs to update Slider (child) as well as App (parent)...

Comment: @Extelliqent Sorry, but I don't understand what scenario you are trying to describe or why it causes any complication beyond the scenario already shown. Please create a new question showing the problem in detail.